# Podman: Network between users

Tags: linux, networking, docker-compose, podman, podman-compose

Disclaimer: Please consider that I am not only new to Podman, but containerisation as whole :)

If I understand the concept of the rootless approach correctly, you should be able to not only run unprivileged containers, but isolate them through the use of a single user for one service.

I want to be able to have a network to communicate between Pods of different users.

I've done some test by creating a pod for a caddy reverse proxy on the user proxy:

```
version: "3.8"
services:
    caddy:
        image: docker.io/caddy
        container_name: caddy
        restart: unless-stopped
        ports:
            - 80:80
            - 443:443
        network:
            - proxy
        volumes:
            - ./Caddyfile:/etc/caddy/Caddyfile:ro
            - caddy_data:/data
            - caddy_config:/config

networks:
  proxy:
    external: true

volumes:
  caddy_data:
  caddy_config:
```

The second user and service should be a webserver:

```
version: "3.8"
services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:ro
    networks:
      - proxy

networks:
  proxy:
    external: true
```

My problem is that I obviously cannot access the network I created for the user proxy for my webserver user: RuntimeError: External network [proxy] does not exists

If I want to isolate my services, I would have to separate them on a user level, so how can I communicate between them? Is there a way to make the network accessible from both Podman instances?

I've done some research for: Podman network between users, Podman global network, but didn't find anything relevant.

Comment: You would not typically try to isolate your containers by running them under different user accounts. Your choices are, broadly, run them all as the same non-root user (better security posture but some limits on what the pod can do), or them all as root (more flexibility but some increased risk in the event of a service compromise).

Comment: But wouldn't that mean that if a container gets compromised all the data managed by that user is at risk? Like if I have an email server and a webserver and the webserver gets compromised all the sensitive data of my email is at risk.

Comment: Sure, running each pod under a distinct user account gives you an enhanced security posture. But you also give up many of the conveniences available when working with containers (primarily around networking and service discovery, although it also requires additional disk space for per-user image stores, etc). Only you can decide where you sit on the security-vs-convenience line.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same idea but no direct solution. You could make the ports of the nginx web server public to the host and configure the reverse proxy to use your host instead directly the nginx server.

But this approach has two disadvantage.

1. You need to secure the access to nginx from outside in another way, e.g. via a firewall rule.
2. The ports are used on your host system. So you cannot easily use port 80 and 443 and also not easily reuse for many containers.